# Is there any way to view the names of files from before iTunes renamed them?

Tags: itunes, finder, filesystem, logs, macos

So here's my sad story guys. I'm a songwriter and I have a ton of audio files on my computer. I spent the last week or so going through them all (some were in iTunes, some were scattered across the HD), renaming them and putting dates in the filenames so that they were organized in folders by "unfinished", "finished", "arrangements", etc. I had this pretty much finished when I decided (stupidly) that I would create a new iTunes library to put them in, so that I could preview them more effectively than you can in the Finder. But I didn't know at the time that the "Keep files organized" option was checked in the preferences, or that it even existed. So after I put them in iTunes, all the files were renamed to their original filenames, and for the most part had any characters in brackets removed.

But here comes the really dumb part: I saw this, and though - ah, never mind, it's not worth it. And deleted the files from iTunes, clicking move to trash - thinking, that iTunes would simply move the newly created folders to the trash. But no - it moved the files into the trash from my old folders! The ones that were located on the Desktop, not my music folders! And it left the files in the Media folder in the iTunes folder alone. What the hell...

So now I'm trying to see if there's some way to look at a system log, or some other kind of data file which might show the renaming process to get back the original names. I'm also hoping that none of the original files were deleted from the computer, but it's hard to tell, since they were all renamed!

Can anyone help me salvage a week of (albeit probably unnecessary) work?

Comment: Is there any chance you have Time Machine enabled and working?

Comment: If only I did... :(